# What are the gameplay/level design differences between Jumper and Jumper: Redux?

Tags: version-differences, jumper, jumper-redux

I understand that in [Jumper:Redux,](http://www.mattmakesgames.com/) graphics and sound effects are improved over the original Jumper. As well a few new features have been added, like multiplayer. What I want to know though is there any differences in core level design or gameplay that would change the actual way the two games are played? Or are they identical in that respect?

(I am thinking of things like in Super Mario Bros 3 the GBA/SNES versions are considered slightly easier than the original NES version)